# Weird behaviour with ksh?

Tags: ksh

So I found something somewhat interesting in `ksh`.  I found that if the last character is `\`, then immediately backspace, the charcter becomes recplaced with `^H`.  I am then able to press backspace again to clear it away.

**What kind of wizardry am I dealing with here?  Is this a bug?**  Trying this in `bash` did not yield the same result.

Comment: The OS is AIX 5.3.  Not sure what version of ksh (looking now), but what I mean is that the very last symbol is literally `\ `.  I forgot the context in which I found myself backspacing `\ `, but I tried it again later and found the same thing..

Comment: I reproduced it in ksh93 on Linux, and all I needed was `set -o vi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's intentional, although I won't disagree about it being weird. When vi or emacs mode is enabled (`set -o vi` or `set -o emacs`) ksh provides this feature (which is present in neither vi nor emacs as far as I know) where the backslash quotes a following control character.

It's like the `lnext` character (Ctrl-V) but weaker. You can enter a literal backspace this way, but to enter a literal `^C` you need the `^V` first.